# Switch between images selecting radios

Tags: html, css

### Explanation

I want to switch between images selecting radios, but I'd like it to be HTML/CSS only. As you can see in the code below, it does work, but in my main code the radio button and the image are within their own `divs`, which then this code won't work because `~` only acts if `.radio-image` is directly preceded by `input.radio3:checked`; also in my main code, the images comes before the radio button.

I also wrote an example like it'd in my main code.

### Codes

**working code**

```css
input.radio1:checked~.image1 {
  display: block;
}
input.radio1:checked~.image2 {
  display: none;
}
input.radio1:checked~.image3 {
  display: none;
}

input.radio2:checked~.image2 {
  display: block;
}
input.radio2:checked~.image1 {
  display: none;
}
input.radio2:checked~.image3 {
  display: none;
}

input.radio3:checked~.image3 {
  display: block;
}
input.radio3:checked~.image1 {
  display: none;
}
input.radio3:checked~.image2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="test" class="radio1" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="test" class="radio2" />
<input type="radio" name="test" class="radio3" />


<div class="image1">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
<div class="image2">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75">
</div>
<div class="image3">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

**main code example**

```css
input.radio1:checked~.image1 {
  display: block;
}

input.radio1:checked~.image2 {
  display: none;
}

input.radio1:checked~.image3 {
  display: none;
}

input.radio2:checked~.image2 {
  display: block;
}

input.radio2:checked~.image1 {
  display: none;
}

input.radio2:checked~.image3 {
  display: none;
}

input.radio3:checked~.image3 {
  display: block;
}

input.radio3:checked~.image1 {
  display: none;
}

input.radio3:checked~.image2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="testSection">

  <div class="firstDiv">
    <div class="image1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50">
    </div>
    <div class="image2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/75x75">
    </div>
    <div class="image3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="secondDiv">
    <form class="testForm">
      <div class="thirdDiv">
        <div class="inputDiv">
          <input type="radio" name="test" class="radio1" checked />
        </div>
        <div class="inputDiv">
          <input type="radio" name="test" class="radio2" />
        </div>
        <div class="inputDiv">
          <input type="radio" name="test" class="radio3" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</section>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this in only HTML/CSS, can you use a bit of JS as well?

Comment: I can, but I was trying to avoid using JS in situations that HTML/CSS were possible. I was hoping to someone who knows better than me (you probably haha) come with a solution.

Comment: No, don't think it's possible. Any CSS only solution would require that the images are adjacent to the radios

Comment: That's what I thought :(

Comment: I tried using `label`s to get it to work, but no dice :(

Comment: I guess it isn't possible then. Thanks for your attempt anyway!!

Comment: @Luiz it may be possible using `:target` ...

Comment: Hi! Could you help me with it? I tried using :target, but all I came up was this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ho07byv/) :(

Comment: @Luiz I tried to figure something out but couldn't get it to work exactly like you wanted. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/3ho07byv/1/) was the best I could come up with... I think javascript would be the easiest thing to use.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt!! I'll use JS by now, but I'm leaving the question here hoping someday HTML/CSS allows this feature :)